# How do I get details about how the view controller will look post-rotation from viewWillTransitionToSize?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8

`viewWillTransitionToSize` gives us a size and a transitionCoordinator. If my view is about to rotate, I want to find what certain elements will be post-rotation so I can tweak values before to be appropriate for the new rotated size.

Am I able to get a reference to the rotated view controller from transitionCoordinator? I know it has `viewControllerForKey:` but I don't know what the key is.

The size it passes is just the size of `viewController.view`, which isn't helpful enough. I need to be able to ask what size a label will be after the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using auto-layout or something that makes it non-trivial to know the final size of your UI element.

I don't believe your view is resized at the time `viewWillTransitionToSize` is called, so no layout has happened.

What you would need to do is force a resize yourself, measure the UI element, then resize the view back to its original size (so that it can animate out to the new size on rotation).

In this case let's assume you want to know about a `UILabel` called `_myLabel`:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    // _myLabel is the label we want to measure
    // This prints out its size pre-rotation:

    NSLog(@"Label size: %f, %f", _myLabel.bounds.size.width, _myLabel.bounds.size.height);

    CGRect oldFrame = self.view.frame;

    //Force this view controller's view to take on the 
    // new size and re-layout immediately

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    // _myLabel's size will now be the value it would take on post-rotation:

    NSLog(@"Label size (after rotation): %f, %f", _myLabel.bounds.size.width, _myLabel.bounds.size.height);

    //Restore the view so it can animate into the new size normally

    self.view.frame = oldFrame;
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This is quite a heavy-handed solution to your problem. It would be better if you could come up with a way to compute your layout independently for the things you need to measure (though I can see how this might just be too complicated).